# Deploy the Build on multiple output folders

Tags: deployment, tfs, tfsbuild

I'm using the Continuous Integration system of TFS and I currently deploy it on a stage server : `\\server1\deploy\`

I would like to do it on multiple server from the same build, like :

```
\\server1\deploy\
\\server2\deploy\
```

is it possible ? How could I do it ?

Comment: Team Foundation Server 2012

Answer (score 2):

You could update the build process template (XAML file) to add an additional step.

I would keep the default publish folder as it is for reference, and push the artifacts to each of the deployment servers as a second step.